# SSRS Report set value of parameter based on other parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I want to set the default value of 1 of my parameter using the other selected parameters dataset value.
for example, the content of the dataset is something like

```
[{'name': alex, 'id': 1},
{'name': bloom, 'id': 2},
{'name': kelly, 'id': 3},
{'name': david, 'id': 4},
{'name': lyn, 'id': 5}];
```

then in previous parameter, the user choose for name = alex, then how to set the next parameter value = 1, which the previous parameter's id.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the parameter properties of the one you want to default > go to Default Values tab > Specify values > add 1 value and use this expression:

```
=Parameters!YourParameterName.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you need two parameters essentially pointing to the same thing?

Typically you would point you parameter's `available values` property to your dataset and set the parameter values to be `ID` and the parameter label to be `name`. This way the user chooses "Alex" from the list but internally the parameter value is actually `1`